# Sorting strings with numbers and text in Rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, ancestry

In my database I have table with a name column containing grades, like 1. grade, 2. grade, and so on. When the numbers have reached 10 or more, the sorting doesn't work as I would like, as 10. grade comes before 2. grade in the sorted recordset. I know this is because string sorting is different from integer sorting. The question is how to sort these strings in a numeric way.

Because the grade-records are a part of a tree buildt with the ancestry plugin, I have to put the whole sorting code inside  :order => "(some code that sorts the results)".

I have tried `:order => "CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '.') AS SIGNED)"`. But this doesn't work.

I use SQLite in my development environment and MySQL in the production environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

replace the constant vale '. grade' of your column with empty string, then you get the numeric value. cast the same to int

```
order by cast(replace(name,'. grade','') as int)
```

**EDIT**:

as per your comment if its not 'grade' always, then try

```
order by cast(left(name,LOCATE('.',name,1)-1) as  UNSIGNED)
```

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37813/1)

Comment: Thanks! That works really well! But there is also a second problem: Sometimes the ". grade" part of the string will be something different, i.e. in another language (". trinn"). There may be several languages. Is there a way to remove everything in a string from a given character, like everything after the number (including the '.')?

Comment: It works, but not in the development environment (SQLite). But that's OK. I just put the sorting inside an `if Rails.env.production?´. Thanks a lot!